# Links disappear when changing to a different template

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm trying to create a blogging website in Django. I'm pretty much a beginner so this question is probably silly but I don't know how to fix this.

I have a main navigation in my header. In the base.html template I created links in the menu for a couple of pages. In the same template I have a list of categories in the sidebar which are links to listing all posts within that category.

When I go to any other template (when I click any of those links), even though I extend the base.html template, the links disappear. How can I keep them in place regardless of the template? What's the common practice for things like this?

Thanks for reading!
Cheers!

EDIT: The code:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">HOME</a></li>
    {% for link in links %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'page' link.slug %}">{{ link.title }} </a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is in the base.html, but those links (except for the hardcoded Home link) disappear in other templates which just change the content block.

EDIT 2: 
Here's the view for the base:

```
def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    links = Page.objects.filter(menu='Y')
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/base.html', {'posts': posts,
                                              'links': links,
                                              'categories': categories,
                                              })
```

SOLUTION:
Thanks everyone for your help. Here's the solution I used:

```
from django.template import RequestContext

def base_links(request):
    header_links = Page.objects.filter(menu='Y')
    sidebar_categories = Category.objects.all()
    return  {
        'links': header_links,
        'categories': sidebar_categories,
    }
```

And then I've added:

```
context_instance = RequestContext(request, processors=[base_links])
```

to all my views.

Comment: Could you please post your templates? Have you included `{% extends 'myapp/base.html' %}` in the other templates?

Comment: I've posted a code of the links. All other templates extend the base.html template.

Comment: How is `links` being passed to the context?

Comment: I've added the code in the post.

Comment: If you read the doc about context processors, you'll find out you DONT have to add anything to your views (except making sure they use a `RequestContext`) - just add your custom context processor to your `settings.CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your templates are passed the current's view's context, so you cannot expect the `index()` views's context to become magically available everywhere.

The two common solutions to make such data available in other templates are

1. a context processor:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

It's a very easy solution, but it has a couple downsides too:
- the context processor will be called even for templates that don't need it
- it makes it hard to know what's really available in the context and where it comes from
- you may end up with two conflicting processors trying to set the same keys in the context
- you may end up with conflicts between processors and views (each trying to set the same keys in the context).

2. custom template tags:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/

In your case, if you plan on presenting the same data in the same way on each and every page of the site, an [`inclusion_tag()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) is the obvious choice.

As far as I'm concerned, I find custom tags to be much more maintainable than context processors, and with the `inclusion_tag()` shortcut they are as easy to setup as context processors.

Answer (score -1):

In django each "page" is a view. Your `index()` function is the view for your homepage and i bet that you have a `blog_post()` or something like that that renders the posts

Each view must define the template to use and pass the context (variables) needed to render it's template. Your base template has a menu that needs the `links` variable, so **every** view that renders a template extending the base template **must** pass the `links` variable to the context.

In simple words :) you need to pass the `links` variable to the context in your post's view

**Small advice:** don't use functions as views. It's better to use [Class Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/)

Hope this helps

Comment: @pleasdontbelong:  as far as I'm concerned, class based views are a major PITA for 99.99% of my use cases. I don't see how adding useless accidental complexity can be "better" than KISS.

Comment: "you need to pass the links variable to the context in your post's view" : so you advise the OP to duplicate this code in each and every view ? And to fork third-part apps views by the way ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers no waaaay. I use CBV every day and i consider using functions the real PITA. Even in this case wit a CBV he could create a mixin that automatically adds the `links` in the context for all the views implementing the mixin, (but this is no place for debate :P)

Comment: "I use CBV every day and i consider using functions the real PITA" => well that was my point exactly: this is a subjective opinion, not a technical fact nor a widely agreed-upon best practice.

Comment: wrt/ adding a mixin to each and every view, that's not what I'd consider as a clean, well-decoupled, maintainable solution. First it forces you to use CBVs, then you DO have to spread that mixin to *each and every view*, including third-part apps views, for a feature that is totally orthogonal to what these views are responsible for. Making "site-global" stuff globally available to all templates without cluttering your views with totally unrelated concerns  is what context processors and template tags are for.